# Prove that the fundamental group of $P^2$ the real projective plane is the group with two elements

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Presumably the group will just contain $e$ and another $g$. My idea is to use the proof that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ where the covering map from $S^2$ to $P^2$ maps to the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ through $0$ and $x$. But I only have very vague ideas of how to show this.

Comment: What is your definition of the projective plane? Do you perhaps know how to realize it as the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^2$ by the action of a group?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629595/fundamental-group-of-projective-plane-is-c-2


If you know Van Kampen: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386805/need-help-understanding-statement-of-van-kampens-theorem-and-using-it-to-comput

And the fundamental polygon of the projective plane is explained here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538720/fundamental-polygon-of-real-projective-plane